# Difference between KVL and mesh analysis

Tags: analysis, network, mesh-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws, circuit-analysis

Are KVL and mesh analysis, the same? I am confused.

What is the characteristic difference between them?

Comment: Same thing......

Comment: Read https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-10/mesh-current-method/

Comment: Any analysis is based on KVL, KCL and Ohm's Law. The Mesh, nodal and others are just the way to derive the complete set of equations.

Comment: @DKNguyen No, not the same thing. A loop is not necessarily a mesh.

Answer (score 2):

Kirchhoff's Voltage Law (KVL) is a rule that says for lumped circuits, the sum of voltage drops across the branches in any chosen loop will be zero. It is essentially a statement that the electric field is a [conservative field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field) in this class of circuits. Or, put another way, that the voltage at each node is a well-defined quantity (given an arbitrary choice of reference voltage).

Mesh analysis is an algorithm for using KVL to solve circuits. Like any algorithm, it requires a finite sequence of steps be performed and produces an result (the currents in all the branches of the circuit). The steps include identifying the meshes of the circuit, writing the KVL equation for each mesh, and solving the system of equations produced.

One is a rule describing the physics of the circuit. The other is an algorithm that uses that rule to solve (determine the currents and voltages of) the circuit.